# Disable use of double-height rows in special folders (trash, etc.) in Files

Tags: nautilus, trash, 23.04

In Files I always show files and folders as rows of the smallest possible height, since this corresponds most closely to what I use in other OSes and is by far the most conducive for quickly scanning the contents of a folder without distractions. In some special folders, though, like the trash, starred, and most recent folders, the row height is doubled to show contextual information (e.g. the original location for trashed items).

I find it very distracting when the same exact UI has multiple visual representations for the same type of item, and would really prefer if the contextual info was just shown in an additional column, or not at all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible without changing the program code of the software. Because many of us lack the programming skills to make a program work the way we would like it to work, the only option for us is to file an issue to the developers, which they then may consider or not.